# Rails: How can I retrieve values from columns named `id`?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `Rails 4.2.6`. I've got a table like this (please forgive the odd table & field namings -- they're from an ancient non-Rails project):

```
mysql> desc user;
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| ...             | ...                 | ...  | ... | ...       | ...            |
| id_number       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment |
| id              | varchar(128)        | NO   | UNI | NULL      |                |
| ...             | ...                 | ...  | ... | ...       | ...            |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `id` field contains strings identifying users, like `"alea12"`. 
My model for this table is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'user'
  self.primary_key = 'id_number'
end
```

When I try to retrieve an `User.id` using `ActiveRecord`, it wouldn't let me to do so.
In MySQL:

```
mysql> select id_number, id from user where id = "alea12" \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id_number: 15966
       id: alea12
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In `rails c`:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.where(id: "alea12")
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 'alea12'
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 'alea12'
=> [#<User:0x007f79c4bfe8a8
  id_number: 15966,
  id: 15966,
  ...,
  updated_date: nil>]
```

I expect the `id` field to be "alea12", but it returns the integer same as `id_number`.
Are there any options to retrieve values from columns named `id` like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you've to override all these public methods in **PrimaryKey** module of **ActiveRecord** related to `id`. [See this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb)

So don't waste your time and write a migration and shift all your `id_number` data to `id` & vice versa.

PS: Using `id` as a primary key is the best practice in Rails!

Thanks